# Как найти объекты в списке python?

Tags: python, алгоритм, list, список

Есть функция которая отправляет список на сервер. Эта функция может вернуть либо “true”, при удачной загрузке, либо загружаемый список полностью, при неудачной. Неудачной загрузка может быть из-за любого «битого» элемента списка.

Предположим, что есть очень большой список. Мы его делим на равные, более мелкие, списки и к каждому из них применяем эту функцию. Как найти все «битые» элементы списка самым правильным и быстрым способом?

П.с. Код тут не важен. Я хочу понять логику перебора/откидывания и опять перебора для «просеивания» элементов

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Хотя бы опишите критерии "битости" элементов списка - какие считаются нормальными, какие - нет.

Comment: Критерии неизвестны, к сожалению. Если знать критерий, то можно фильтровать до загрузки на сервер, а так я узнаю, что элемент невалидный только после отправки запроса и получения либо true, либо этого самого списка обратно. Проблема ещё и в том, что ответ сервера относительно долгий (1-2 секунды), иначе я бы отправлял по одному элементу и не парился.

Comment: Я же говорю. Время критично. Список элементов для загрузки может достигать длинны до 5 миллионов элементов. А это при лучшем раскладе 50 дней.

Comment: Да, я не заметил сначала, поэтому удалил комент

Comment: А алгоритм по которому сервер проверяет ссылки на битость известен?

Comment: Нет. Вот и маемся. В данной реализации количество подсписков с битыми элементами получается не больше 10% от общего количества. И мы пока решили просто откидывать весь подсписок и продолжать загрузку следующего. В будущем хотелось бы выжать максимум из загрузки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я пока никакой другой логики кроме рекурсии не вижу здесь.
Вот пример (*псевдо*)кода, с эмуляцией ответов сервера, который битыми считает строковые элементы в списке:

```
baddata=[]

def servresp(a:list): #эмулируем работу с сервером
    try:
        result=sum(a) #проверяем список. если он валидный, проглатываем его
        print("{} slice is OK, accepting.".format(a))
        return True   #и возвращаем True
    except:
        print("{} - bad slice, sending back.".format(a))
        return a      #а если нет - возвращаем сам список

def proc(a:list):
    parts=[]                            #эти три строки
    parts.append(a[:len(a)//2])         #делят список
    parts.append(a[len(a)//2:])         #пополам
    for part in parts:                  #каждую половину отправляем на сервер
        res=servresp(part)              #проверяем ответ сервера
        if not isinstance(res, bool):   #если ответ не True (возвращен список)         
            if len(res)==1:             #если список состоит из одного элемента, то он "битый"
                print("{} - erroneous input!".format(res))
                baddata.append(res)
            else:                       #а если нет - то продолжаем идти
                proc(res)               # по списку рекурсивно

mylist=[1,2,3,'a','b', 4,5,6]
proc(mylist)
print("Bad pieces of list are: {}".format(baddata))
```

Получим такое:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'a'] - bad splice, sending back.
[1, 2] slice is OK, accepting.
[3, 'a'] - bad splice, sending back.
[3] slice is OK, accepting.
['a'] - bad splice, sending back.
['a'] - erroneous input!
['b', 4, 5, 6] - bad splice, sending back.
['b', 4] - bad splice, sending back.
['b'] - bad splice, sending back.
['b'] - erroneous input!
[4] slice is OK, accepting.
[5, 6] slice is OK, accepting.
Bad pieces of list are: [['a'], ['b']]
```

Comment: Спасибо, видимо, действительно нет другого решения при данных условиях. Ушел колдовать.